# Simple R function with variable number of arguments

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working on a project converting a bunch of stata code to R to perform data cleaning, and one of the things I'm trying to do is to write a single R function that cleans all of my Yes/No variables that were previously coded as (Yes = 1, No = 2) to standard dummy variables.

The thing is that the number of variables that need to be cleaned by this function will constantly be changing. So my guess is that the function will need to take as its arguments (1) the dataset/dataframe with all the variables, and (2) the list of variables that need to be cleaned.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, as I'm pretty new to R.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have as input : **data sample** ?What do you want : **expected result**? what have you tried : **some R code**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
example <- data.frame(sex=runif(10),q1=rep.int(c(1,2),5),q2=rep.int(c(2,1),5))

yesno <- function(data, variables) {
  data.new <- data
  data.new[,names(data) %in% variables] <- -data[,names(data) %in% variables]+2
  return(data.new)
}

example
yesno(example, c("q1","q2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sapply(data, function(x) {-x+2})`

`data` contains your columns of 1, 2. The anonymous functions turns all Yes/1 into 1, and No/2 into 0.